# Can I completely disable #include lookups?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code

Whenever I open C (or C++) files in Visual Studio Code, I get the infamous errors about not being able to open `#include` files and requesting that I update my `includePath`.

I do not wish to touch `includePath`; I am editing source code from a network share, the machine my editor runs on does not have a development environment, and I therefore cannot satisfy Visual Studio Code's desire to find standard library headers.  I just want to edit code.

Is there any way that I can disable `#include` lookups entirely?  I know that I can suppress the warning, but I can't suppress the error squigglies, and I would prefer that my editor not even bother wasting time doing unnecessary reads from the file system.

If it helps, I don't really care about IntelliSense.

Comment: Why not use any old text editor?

Comment: @n.m. Because I still want a *code* editor with things like syntax highlighting, brace matching, automatic indentation, having a multiline cursor, etc.

Comment: But without the includes it's impossible to parse the syntax.

Comment: E.g. notepad++ provides syntax highlighting but does not care about any `#include` path. @n.m. It's not that old but, I believe, a new one does as well.

Comment: Explore alternatives such as Sublime Text, Gedit, Eclipse.

Comment: The only text editor I regularly encounter these days that does *not* have these features is Windows Notepad.

Comment: @RustyX The language grammar is known.  There might be some cases where the editor doesn't know if an identifier is a type or function or macro (especially with C++), but if it has to guess in ambiguous cases, so be it.  Currently VS Code seems to do a reasonable job of doing syntax highlighting without me setting `includePath`.

Comment: @Ron I have indeed spent the past several days trying (and customizing) Sublime, Atom, Notepad++, VS Code, etc., and all of the others have different, worse issues that I can't seem to fix with customization.

Comment: vscode is [open source](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode). Feel free to dig through the code and if there is no setting for this, to implement it.

Comment: Tool recommendations are off-topic here. That goes for questions, as well as for derailing questions with tool recommendations in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling the Microsoft C/C++ extension (ms-vscode.cpptools) appears to disable  `#include` lookups.  Disabling that extension also disables some other behaviors for C and C++, of course, but I think I can live with that.